# Determining why settings says "Unknown Display" in 21.10

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution

I have recently built a system with a Intel CPU with embedded graphics.  I have installed Ubuntu 21.10 and it says "Unknown Display" in the settings and I cannot change the display resolution from 1024x768 even though the monitor supports much higher resolution.

I ran across a discussion about using inxi -G and saw that it said driver "N/A" so I thought I needed the latest Intel drivers.  Here was my output:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 driver: N/A 
  Display: server: X.org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa tty: 80x24 
  Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console for root.
```

I built the latest media-driver from GitHub and installed it (not without a bit of pain) and still have the same result.

That means I don't understand the problem or what to look at.

What diagnostics should I be doing to determine why I am prevented from changing the screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=6c4ff21b02 you have to get newest possible linux kernel for this Ubuntu version. Or upgrade whole system to 22.04 LTS by `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` or `update-manager -cd` with its 5.15 kernel and test possible progress here.

Comment: Thanks.  That helped me get to the right answer.  The linux hardware site was useful.  I ended up going to the 5.16 kernel on 21.10 (because 22.04 isn't out yet).  This article helped me get the kernel updated: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685830/how-to-use-5-16-kernel-with-ubuntu-21-10